# How to update and insert with a single MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to insert and update a table using one mysql query my table structure is:

```
student_id ,class_no, section, started_on ,ended_on
```

I want to update `class_no` and insert a new records. For that I am using  this query:

```
INSERT INTO student_classes (student_id,class_no,section,started_on,ended_on) 
VALUES (835,5,0,2013-04-09,null) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE class_no = class_no+1
```

but this query is only insert a new row,not updated  column if I use where clause after `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE class_no = class_no+1` its give error message.

Message is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'where started_on=2013-04-09'

Comment: The error is definitely from a different query since the query you have shown does not contain 'where started_on=...'

Comment: yes if I used where clause in my query its gave error

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko INSERT INTO student_classes (student_id,class_no,section,started_on,ended_on) 
VALUES (835,5,0,2013-04-09,null) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE class_no = 'class_no+1' where started_on=2013-04-09 and if I used this qury INSERT INTO student_classes (student_id,class_no,section,started_on,ended_on) 
VALUES (835,5,0,2013-04-09,null) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE class_no = class_no+1. its only insert data into table not updated

Comment: Please add the output of `show create table student_classes;` in your question (or just describe how fields are created and what keys are used)

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student_classes` (
  `student_class_id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `class_no` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `section` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `started_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ended_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_class_id`),
  KEY `student_id` (`student_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2222 ;
@AndreiNikolaenko this is my table output :

Comment: Thank you. So your values on insert are: `student_id = 835, class_no = 5, section = 0, started_on = '2013-04-09', ended_on = null`. Of them, only student_id is a unique key. If your query does insert, then it means there is no student_id = 835 in the table, or else insert would not happen. Other duplicated fields are ignored because they are not keys. If yout want insert or update on some field, you need to declare that field as a key. Because the query says: `on duplicate key` :)

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko Thanks and sorry student_id is not unique_key, unique is student_class_id and that is auto increment I want to insert new recored for student_id =835 and also want to update class_no column

Comment: Oh, indeed `student_id` is not unique. Then you need to make it unique or it will not work. Because the mySQL documentation says, "If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed."

Comment: As an alternative, you don't have to use a single SQL query. You can do a SELECT first, and then insert or update based on the results of select.